# Excel: Calculate average time (duration), with criteria, between 2 columns

Tags: excel, time, timestamp, average, duration

Breaking my head over this, time to look for help :(
I have a sheet with raw data, as illustrated below.
I'd like to calculate the average duration per TestName (column A) between the 2 timestamps (B and C) in another sheet.

How can I do this in 1 formula?

Note 1: The correct answer is (done manually)
test1 = 26:41:23
test2 = 08:23:10

Note 2: 1 formula please, without adding extra columns to calculate the duration per each first
Note 3: I cannot change the format of the raw data
Note 4: ignore empty fields

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are those real datetimes that you forced left alignment on or are they text?

Comment: +Jeeped: this is text

Comment: Why would you so that? It makes no sense.

Comment: @NicoF How is `test1` calculated as `26:41:23` ?

Comment: +Jeeped: why? I can create a column D, format as Time, and =C-B will give me the duration. In another cell I can do =AVERAGEIF(A:A,"test1",D:D) which seems to work, however I can't figure out 1 formula.

Comment: @NicoF - Comments are not the right place for Jeeped (or anyone) to provide a tutorial on working with dates in Excel, nor an detailed explanation of **why** it's best to store dates *the way Excel intends*.  (There are several reasons.)  Instead, [**here is a link**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Working+with+dates+and+times+in+Excel) with explanation.  Indeed it's a Google search, but I'm not being the facetious -- I'd suggest you review all top 4 or 5 results on that search to help you understand the in's and out's of working with dates & times in Excel; it's important basic knowledge.

Comment: @PaichengWu - Looks like the average of the hours between the two start and finish dates for Test1 (ignoring the one without a finish date)

Comment: @NicoF - One more thought - when reading those links you'll see that Excel is very flexible about how you *display* (format) date & times, but unless there's a specific reason to use the format you're currently using, I'd highly recommended `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` (easily remembered as largest to smallest) -- because of several advantages I won't get into here.

Comment: @ashleedawg I cannot modify the raw data, however it seems not to be a problem (not sure). I created a Google sheet with some real data to illustrate how I can get my result by creating first a column D, however I'd like to get the Yellow cells by using 1 formula. Hope this helps!
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ajfLh8X2Nhr1kAIgoyF_XMFqshK2liqDhDUK7kE0GHM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Use a new Column D to calculate the difference between start and end date on each row:

```
=DATEVALUE(C2)+TIMEVALUE(C2) - (DATEVALUE(B2)+TIMEVALUE(B2))
```

Next calculate the average on test1 and test2

```
=AVERAGEIFS($D:$D, $A:$A, "test1")
=AVERAGEIFS($D:$D, $A:$A, "test2")
```

Note that I'm using a comma as separator, in some languages, other separators, like semicolon are needed to write the formulas properly.

Now format the view to display at least the days in addition to the time: "DD - hh:mm:ss". Going beyond 31 days is a bit difficult as the month will count up.
If you don't like the formatting, go with the raw number format and extract the information through a bit of math. If it shows for example 1,5 it means one and a half days. I hope you can handle converting decimals to hours, minutes and seconds. MOD(ulo) and Rounddown are going to be your friends. :-)

Comment: thx for your answer. Ihave done something simular, see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ajfLh8X2Nhr1kAIgoyF_XMFqshK2liqDhDUK7kE0GHM/edit?usp=sharing

Can it be done without creating D first?

Comment: Yes you can, but you'll need to be confident in handling array formulas and it will likely be slower. Especially if you do not convert the range into a table. `{=SUM(IF(Table1[name]="test1";DATEVALUE(Table1[end]) +TIMEVALUE(Table1[end]) -  (DATEVALUE(Table1[start])+TIMEVALUE(Table1[start]));0)) / SUM(IF(Table1[name]="test1";1;0))}`  And no it will probably not work in google sheets.